# Moving over conceal

Tags: cursor-movement

Is there a setting that allows you to move over `conceal`ed strings as if they were one (or even better: zero) characters? ([This answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2492/3316) seems to suggest there's not.)

As it is, any movement can land on the concealment character. For example, `fa` will land on a following ceoncealment if it contains the character `a`, rather than skipping it to the next `a` on the line. This can be very annoying.

Comment: It probably helps (at least with `f` , `t` etc.) if you don't conceal the current line - by disabling `n` from the `'concealcursor'` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such setting. Concealing only means to visually hide parts of your buffer, but that won't affect movements nor linebreaking.

"Fixing" this is in the todo list, but I wouldn't bet it will be implemented within the foreseeable future, as it will likely introduce even more conceal bugs.